# osquery - How can I retrieve a file origin using osquery?

Tags: sql, windows, osquery

I'm using osquery on Windows and I need help: I want to retrieve the file origin of a specific file. For example I download a file from http://example.com and I'm looking for a query on osquery that show me the info that I download that specific file from http://example.com (or something like this). I thought that to derive this information I can compare the timestamps between the table *file* and the table *routes* but there isn't the column *timestamp* in *routes*. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a table for this on windows, although the information is available on the system through ADS([see this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/695507/find-out-where-a-file-was-downloaded-from)). I would open an issue for this on the [osquery repo](https://github.com/facebook/osquery/issues), it would be a valuable table to have.

You can use the `extended_attributes` table. For example:

```
osquery> select path, key, value, base64 from extended_attributes where path ='/Users/victor/Downloads/osqueryi.zip';
  path = /Users/victor/Downloads/osqueryi.zip
   key = com.apple.lastuseddate#PS
 value = eynzWgAAAAAbZEQgAAAAAA==
base64 = 1

  path = /Users/victor/Downloads/osqueryi.zip
   key = where_from
 value = https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T04QVKUQG-FALAL3WP2/download/osqueryi.zip
base64 = 0
osquery>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I don't have Mac OS. I thought about using a virtual machine with Mac OS, but I found an interesting way to retrieve the information I want: if I download a file using Google Chrome, I can retrieve `ReferrerURL` and `HostURL` from the `Zone.Identifier` file. It doesn't work for `.exe` file and I don't know why. I do that because osquery doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 1):

+1 on what @groob mentioned, this'd be a nice table to have and I think we've wanted it for some time. I thought we already had an issue cut for this, but I went ahead and made a new one as simple searches wasn't turning anything up. Thanks for the question :)
https://github.com/facebook/osquery/issues/5250